# Value of $f(f(x) – 2y) = 2x – 3y + f(f(y) – x)$

Tags: functions

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a polynomial function satisfying

$$f(f(x) – 2y) = 2x – 3y + f(f(y) – x),$$
where $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. Find the value of $$f(21) – f(14).$$

Comment: I am not able to proceed first step in this question

Comment: Isnt this just a typo?! because I calculated $f(21)-f(14)=7$

Comment: Can you show me steps

Comment: @hgs I got the same result as you, i.e., $f(21) - f(14) = 7$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are given

$$f(f(x) – 2y) = 2x – 3y + f(f(y) – x) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Since $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, you can let $x = \frac{3y}{2}$ in \eqref{eq1A} to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f\left(f\left(\frac{3y}{2}\right) - 2y\right) & = 2\left(\frac{3y}{2}\right) - 3y + f\left(f\left(y\right) - \frac{3y}{2}\right) \\
f\left(f\left(\frac{3y}{2}\right) - 2y\right) & = f\left(f\left(y\right) - \frac{3y}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Note $f$ can't be the constant function since \eqref{eq1A} then wouldn't hold for all $x$ and $y$. Actually, as [WhatsUp](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/256378/whatsup)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3529999/value-of-ffx-2y-2x-3y-ffy-x/3530021?noredirect=1#comment7260295_3530021) states, $f$ must be linear. To see this, consider the degree of $f$ to be some $n \gt 1$. Then $f(x) - 2y$ has an $x$ term of degree $n$ and $f(f(x) - 2y)$ has an $x$ term of degree $n^2$. However, on the right side, $f(f(y) - x)$ would only have a highest degree term of $x$ being $n$. Since $n^2 \gt n$, it would not be possible for \eqref{eq1A} to always hold.

Since $f$ must be linear, then

$$f(y) = ay + b \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

for some real $a \neq 0$ and $b$. Let the arguments to the outer $f$ functions in \eqref{eq2A} be $g(y)$ and $h(y)$ to get using \eqref{eq3A} that $ag(y) + b = ah(y) + b \implies a(g(y) - h(y)) = 0 \implies g(y) = h(y)$. Thus, you get

$$f\left(\frac{3y}{2}\right) - 2y = f(y) - \frac{3y}{2} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Using $y = 14$ in \eqref{eq4A} gives

$$f(21) - 28 = f(14) - 21 \implies f(21) - f(14) = 7 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Alternatively, you can use \eqref{eq3A} in \eqref{eq1A} to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f(ax + b - 2y) & = 2x - 3y + f(ay + b - x) \\
a(ax + b - 2y) + b & = 2x - 3y + a(ay + b - x) + b \\
a^2x + ab - 2ay & = 2x - 3y + a^2y + ab - ax \\
a^2x - 2ay & = 2x - 3y + a^2y - ax \\
(a^2 + a - 2)x & = (a^2 + 2a - 3)y 
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

For this to be true for all real $x$ and $y$ requires $a^2 + a - 2 = a^2 + 2a - 3 = 0 \implies a = 1$. Using $a = 1$ in \eqref{eq3A} gives

$$f(21) - f(14) = (21 + b) - (14 + b) = 7 \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

This matches what was obtained in \eqref{eq5A}.

Comment: *For (2) to be true for all $y\in \Bbb R$ means those arguments to the outermost $f$ function must be the same* Why? for example, if $f(x) = x^2$, then we have $f(y) = f(-y)$ while $y$ and $-y$ are not the same.

Comment: Instead, you should first determine the degree of $f$. By comparison of degree, it is clear that $f$ must have degree $1$. Therefore $f$ is a linear function and one can solve the coefficients from the functional equation.

Comment: @WhatsUp Thanks for the feedback, especially for explaining my mistake. You're right the arguments don't have to necessarily be the same in the general case of polynomials. I've updated my answer to explain that $f$ must be linear. I also added solving for the leading coefficient of $f$ being $1$ from the functional equation, to give a second way to determine the result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my Approach:

$f(f(x) – 2y) = 2x – 3y + f(f(y) – x)$

If $x=21,y=14, then: 2x-3y=0$ So

$ f(f(21)-28)=f(f(14)-21)$

$f(21)-f(14)=7$